# How do I continually update my ReactJS client from my Ruby REST/CRUD API without polling?

Tags: javascript, ruby, websocket, reactjs, reactjs-flux

### BACKGROUND

I'm building a simple **ReactJS** application as a proof of concept; with **Flux** architecture and all.

I have a **Ruby** and **MongoDB** data layer API built using **Sinatra** and **Mongoid**.

A front-end served statically using **ReactJS**, **JSX**, and **Fluxxor**.

I currently fetch the application state using a click handler which runs the following function:

```
function(callback){
  var the_url = (this.state.isSelected) ? '/disable' : '/enable' ;
  $.ajax({
    url: the_url,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      callback(data);
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(the_url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
}
```

It is a simple AJAX call. I understand I could achieve some sort of real-time by refactoring a little and having a piece of code similar to the one above running periodically; basically **polling**.

I've read and have been told that the *"true react way"* of doing things would be to have the back-end notifying the front-end when the state of the app changes and that the way to achieve this reliably would be using **WebSockets**.

### BOTTOM-LINE

Taking into account the stack I have described, **what libraries should I use for handling these sockets on either end of the application, and what would the simplest possible implementation look like?**

Comment: You can continually update your client by simply using MeteorJS instead. jk, I'm curious to see what solutions people come up with.

Comment: Changing backend is loads of work, I would probably avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not dependent on you using React, you should use the same way of doing real-time updates as you would if you had used any front-end technique. The problem with WebSockets are mainly that the browser support have been a bit erratic, [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is a quite popular way to get around that.

Socket.io is mostly geared towards Node.js, but should be workable from any backend. [Here](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2012/02/25/adding_real-time_to_rails_with_socket.IO_nodejs_and_backbonejs_with_demo/) is a write-up on using it with Rails.